# Why TimerTask can't be reused into another timer, but already used TimerTask can be reused into ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, timertask

In the code below, the commented out cause the exception that explains us that the `timerTask2` is already scheduled or cancelled, however nothing prevents if from being reused and ran by the executor in the code below the commented out part. How it can be explained?

```
Timer timer2 = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask2 = new ThreadTest6();
delay = 1000 L;
long period = 1000 L;
timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask2, delay, period);

try {
    Thread.sleep(10500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

timer2.purge();
timer2.cancel();
timerTask2.cancel();

//        Timer timer3=new Timer();
//        System.out.println("Task reuse");
//        System.out.println();
//
//        timer3.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask2, delay, period);
//
//        try {
//            Thread.sleep(1500);
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//

System.out.println("At the executor service");
System.out.println();

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
delay = 1000 L;
period = 1000 L;
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask2, delay, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
try {
    Thread.sleep(delay + period * 3);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Because `Timer` checks to see if `TimerTask` has been cancelled (i.e. this behavior is specific to `Timer`). To the `ScheduledExecutorService`, the `TimerTask` is simply a `Runnable`.

Comment: @Slaw thank you, got it. I have supposed the state check is on the task side, not on the timer, so that's why I was surprised. So please put you answer as the offical .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Slaw answered as:

Because `Timer` checks to see if `TimerTask` has been cancelled (i.e. this behavior is specific to `Timer`). To the `ScheduledExecutorService`, the `TimerTask` is simply a `Runnable`